# TaskTracker use local libraries

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When the tasktracker has been assigned a task, it that possible the tasktracker start the task with the library on its local system?

If so, what is the command to enable using local library?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by _it that possible the tasktracker start the task with the library on its local system?_

Comment: Yes, basically I want to pre-install these library to the data node. From this post: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/ I think the only way is using JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

All jars in the local HADOOP_HOME/lib will be added to the class path, so you can just stick stuff in there if you want a quick hack.

The proper way to do it is to explicitly add stuff to the distributed cache before you start your job, then that library will be available to every task of your Map Reduce job.

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("hdfs://path/to/lib.jar"), jobConf)
```

Comment: Or the `-libjars /path/to/local/jar` generic argument will upload the local jar to HDFS and make it available to the tasks

Comment: Chris is correct so long as you've implemented your main method as a "Tool", or your're explicitly passing common args to hadoop using the GenericOptionsParser.